# How to bind gridview templatefield footer textbox to insert parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this gridview with the footer row enabled to insert new rows.  However I don't know how to bind the textbox with insert parameter in the sqldatasource.  Please help?

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Region Name" SortExpression="regionName">
                <FooterTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="tbInsert" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it, did it in code behind:

```
        if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
        {
            TextBox tbInsert = grv_regionManagement.FooterRow.FindControl("tbInsert") as TextBox;
            sds_regions.InsertParameters["regionName"].DefaultValue = tbInsert.Text;
            sds_regions.Insert();
        }
```